# website /url validation in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revWebsite" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
 ControlToValidate="txtWebsite" ErrorMessage="Invalid Website (General Details)"
 ValidationExpression="(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?">*
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

why not working for ? :

www.website.com

www.domain.website.com

http://website.com

https://website.com

Comment: There is not a question here!

Comment: how ..........................

Comment: do you want to check for site existence?

Comment: i just want client site form validation ....like above ..

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** if you want to validate a site a you can check its existence by pining it.

you can use [custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) for that. for that see the below example:

in the .aspx page:

```
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtURL" ValidationGroup="vlg" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfvURL"  ErrorMessage="Please Enter" ControlToValidate="txtURL" ValidationGroup="vlg"
            runat="server" />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstmValURL" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid site" 
            ControlToValidate="txtURL"   runat="server"  ValidationGroup="vlg"
            onservervalidate="cstmValURL_ServerValidate" />
        <asp:Button Text="submit" ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click" ValidationGroup="vlg" />
    </ div>
```

in the .cs page:

```
 protected void cstmValURL_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            if (TestSite())
            {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
        }

        private bool TestSite()
        {         
            Ping objPing = new Ping();
            bool blnResult = false;
            try
            {
                PingReply pngReply = objPing.Send(txtURL.Text.Trim(), 3000);
                if (pngReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                   return blnResult= true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return  blnResult=false;
            }
            return blnResult;
        }
```

**P.S.** This is just a suggestion.

Comment: i want to do with RegularExpressionValidator